React Query fetches data whenever parameters change even though enabled option is set to false
I am aware that if it was an ordinary react component or a custom hook it is supposed to return newly updated data  if props change but since there is no specific details in the documentation I wanted to know if this is the main reason why data fetching ( refetchProducts) happens whenever query params change or I'm missing some configuration that could help prevent this issue.
What I'm trying to achieve is load all products initially since the 3 query params are all empty and then refetch only filtered products whenever filter button is clicked (NOT whenever the 3 Search Pararams are changed). RefetchProducts is invoked on button click. I thought enabled = false would do the job, but apparently I'm mistaken.  Each time any of the 3 Search params ( classification,   vendor,   searchText ) is changed the request to fetch products is sent. This is not happening in any of my event handlers, which means the query does it itself. What am i missing and what is the best approach in such situations?
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import http from "../http";

//  have to filter data
const useGetFilteredProductsQuery = (
  classification,
  vendor,
  searchText,
  options = {}
) => {
  return useQuery({
    ...options,
    queryKey: ["customer/products", classification, vendor, searchText],
    queryFn: () => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams();
      if (classification) params.append("classification", classification);
      if (vendor) params.append("vendor", vendor);
      if (searchText) params.append("searchText", searchText);
      return http.get("/products?" + params.toString(), {
        withCredentials: true, // This ensures cookies are sent with requests
        xsrfCookieName: "token",
      });
    },
    select: (data) => {
      return data.data;
    },
  });
};

export default useGetFilteredProductsQuery;


// component in which the query is used
const { classification, vendor, searchText } = SearchParams; // Zustand store

  const {
    data: classifications = [],
    error: classificationError,
    isLoading: classificationLoading,
  } = useGetClassificationQuery();

  const {
    data: products = [],
    error: productsError,
    isLoading: productsLoading,
    refetch: refetchProducts,
  } = useGetFilteredProductsQuery(classification, vendor, searchText, {
    enabled: false,
  });
  const INITIAL_ENTRIES_PER_PAGE = 3;
  const { page, setPage, displayEntries, pages } = usePagination(
    products,
    INITIAL_ENTRIES_PER_PAGE
  );

// refetchProducts should work only on page load and button click
  useEffect(() => {
    refetchProducts();
  }, []);
...

I tried removing the params from the key array of the query, I tried checking out whether this happens after initial refetchProducts in the useEffect ( removed the useEffect because I know it invalidates the query  so I thought something might be going on with the params that I pass)

are you sure it runs the query again ? How do you observe it ? Maybe you log the cached value and you misintepret it as a refetch

Did you try to store the search params in the local state? I would try to disable the automatic refetchig (by setting enabled: false) and to use refetch manually when the button is clicked. You could also implement the use of a state or flag to determine if it is the initial fetch or not.
I hope this helped clarifying a bit, if you need any more help or if it didn't solve the job, I will be happy to see this issue in more details. Have a good coding session! :)))
